# How can I simplify this distance matrix calculation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I am trying to calculate a distance matrix. The distance between a $v$ vector and an $a$ axis is the norm of the difference between the vector and its orthogonal projection on the axis:

$$||a - v * (v^T * v)^{-1} * v^T * a||$$

Both $v$ and $a$ are in an $n$ dimensional space.

My first question is whether I can simplify this equation itself?

My overall aim is to solve this computationally for ~2000 axes and vectors, but, in this form, this is either very slow or cannot fit into memory. I only interested in the distances. So my second question is how is it the best to solve this in matrix form?

**Updates**

- I can do the computation with a low number of the vectors and axes but not in their matrix form (i.e. with all the ~$2000^2$ combinations)
- Chunking would be my computational solution but I am interested in whether I can solve it with symbolic manipulation (this is why I posted here, although, indeed, this is not a clear-cut case).
- Both vectors have 2000 elements and there are 2025 $v$ vectors and 2000 $a$ vectors. So the $V$ and $A$ respective matrices are of 2025x2000 and 2000x2000 shape.

Comment: Also, can you be a bit more clear about what the parameters of your problem are? Are you given two vectors $a$ and $v$ in an $n$-dimensional space, and want to compute the shortest distance from $v$ to the line spanned by $a$?

Comment: Yes, they are in an $n$-dimensional space and no, I just need the distances. I updated the questions accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't fit into memory? A 2000 x 2000 matrix only takes 32 MB. For each vector you can precompute $v / (v^Tv)$, but that's about it.

Comment: Sorry, yes, this is a bit confusing and neither I was entirely clear. Both vectors have 2000 elements and there are 2025 $v$ vectors and 2000 $a$ vectors. So the $V$ and $A$ respective matrices are of 2025x2000 and 2000x2000 shape. I updated the question with this information.

Comment: I still do not understand the memory issue. All you added is the length of each vector.